# Alter node global variable on runtime

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I need to change the logging level of my node application on runtime whenever I want to on the basis of load on my cassndra servers or purely on an ad-hoc basis. I can think of one way i.e. by creating an endpoint (express route) to alter that variable but was looking for some other solutions that may exist.

Any suggestions/help will be extremely appreciated :)

Comment: I don't know if it is possible with express, but with `fastify` and `pino` logger you can do it https://www.npmjs.com/package/pino-arborsculpture

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to monitor your load via a background task. This could be a simple function that calculates the load, and based on a certain threshold that you decide, can alter your global variable.

Just use *setInterval* to run this background task periodically